# How to NOT repeat a random.choice when printing a piece of text in python

Tags: python, random, repeat

I have three lists in text files and I am trying to generate a four-word message randomly, choosing from the `prefix` and `suprafix` lists for the first three words and the `suffix' file for the fourth word.

However, I want to prevent it from picking a word that was already chosen by the `random.choice` function.

```
import random

a= random.random
prefix = open('prefix.txt','r').readlines()
suprafix = open('suprafix.txt','r').readlines()
suffix = open('suffix.txt','r').readlines()
print (random.choice(prefix + suprafix), random.choice(prefix + suprafix), random.choice(prefix + suprafix), random.choice(suffix))
```

As you can see it chooses randomly from those two lists for three words.

Comment: You could `random.shuffle` and slice the list, or `random.sample`, or store the previous choices and reject them "manually" if they reappear, or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.sample(pop, k)` selected `k` items from `pop` *without replacement*. Hence:

```
prefix1, prefix2, prefix3 = random.sample(prefix, 3)
suprafix1, suprafix2, suprafix3 = random.sample(suprafix, 3)
suffix = random.choice(suffix)
print (prefix1 + suprafix1, prefix2 + suprafix2, prefix3 + suprafix3, suffix))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou xnx that helped me sort out the problem by using the random.sample first then printing either of them afterwards, i might have done it the long way round but this is how i did it >

```
import random
```

a= random.random

prefix = open('prefix.txt','r').readlines()

suprafix = open('suprafix.txt','r').readlines()

suffix = open('suffix.txt','r').readlines()

prefix1, prefix2, prefix3 = random.sample(prefix, 3)

suprafix1, suprafix2, suprafix3 = random.sample(suprafix, 3)

suffix = random.choice(suffix)

one = prefix1, suprafix1

two = prefix2, suprafix2

three = prefix3, suprafix3

print (random.choice(one), random.choice(two), random.choice(three), suffix)